# Connection to neutron failed: Maximum attempts reached

Tags: openstack, icehouse

When I login the dashboard after I input the username and password , it turns out the error page.

```
ConnectionFailed at /project/
Connection to neutron failed: Maximum attempts reached
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://{myip}/horizon/project/
Django Version: 1.6.1
Exception Type: ConnectionFailed
Exception Value:    
Connection to neutron failed: Maximum attempts reached
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py in retry_request, line 1228
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../..',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/',
 '/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard']


Traceback:
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://{myip}/horizon/project/

Django Version: 1.6.1
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
['openstack_dashboard.dashboards.project',
 'openstack_dashboard.dashboards.admin',
 'openstack_dashboard.dashboards.settings',
 'openstack_dashboard',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'compressor',
 'horizon',
 'openstack_auth']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'horizon.middleware.HorizonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')

Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/horizon/decorators.py" in dec
  38.         return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/horizon/decorators.py" in dec
  54.             return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/horizon/decorators.py" in dec
  38.         return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  87.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/horizon/tables/views.py" in get
  154.         handled = self.construct_tables()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/horizon/tables/views.py" in construct_tables
  145.             handled = self.handle_table(table)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/horizon/tables/views.py" in handle_table
  118.         data = self._get_data_dict()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/horizon/tables/views.py" in _get_data_dict
  181.             self._data = {self.table_class._meta.name: self.get_data()}
File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../../openstack_dashboard/dashboards/project/overview/views.py" in get_data
  57.         super(ProjectOverview, self).get_data()
File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../../openstack_dashboard/usage/views.py" in get_data
  44.         self.usage.get_limits()
File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../../openstack_dashboard/usage/base.py" in get_limits
  193.         self.get_neutron_limits()
File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../../openstack_dashboard/usage/base.py" in get_neutron_limits
  151.             api.neutron.is_security_group_extension_supported(self.request)
File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../../openstack_dashboard/api/neutron.py" in is_security_group_extension_supported
  861.     return is_extension_supported(request, 'security-group')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/horizon/utils/memoized.py" in wrapped
  90.             value = cache[key] = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../../openstack_dashboard/api/neutron.py" in is_extension_supported
  841.     extensions = list_extensions(request)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/horizon/utils/memoized.py" in wrapped
  90.             value = cache[key] = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../../openstack_dashboard/api/neutron.py" in list_extensions
  832.     extensions_list = neutronclient(request).list_extensions()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py" in with_params
  111.             ret = self.function(instance, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py" in list_extensions
  294.         return self.get(self.extensions_path, params=_params)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py" in get
  1236.                                   headers=headers, params=params)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py" in retry_request
  1228.         raise exceptions.ConnectionFailed(reason=_("Maximum attempts reached"))

Exception Type: ConnectionFailed at /project/
Exception Value: Connection to neutron failed: Maximum attempts reached
```

“Connection to neutron failed: Maximum attempts reached” when neutron net-list as well.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem. Make sure that Neutron is actually running:

```
service neutron-server status
```

If it's not running:

```
service neutron-server start
```

Comment: In my case neutron-server is running but still the same error.

Trying it on IceHouse  

Also the 9696 port is open